# Sticky navigation element jumps during scroll

Tags: css, scroll, sticky

In Firefox especially, I've run into an issue I can't figure out how to fix.

On the following page, when scrolling down the page jumps several times - mainly on smaller screens where the page doesn't have its full size displayed. You can replicate this issue by making your browser smaller than the page so you have to scroll.

It's on this page: http://www.nucanoe.com/frontier-accessories/

If I disable the `position:fixed` on the navigation selector, it fixes the issue - but we need the navigation to be sticky. Is there a solution to fix this? I'm thinking we may need to use jQuery somehow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

After seeing you asking for help on another answer, I will try and explain more clearly for you.

**The Problem**

Your problem is when you add `position:fixed` to the navigation bar, it removes it from its place and sticks it at the top of the page. This is why the rest of your content jumps up - because the navigation bar is not where it was anymore.

**How To Fix**

You can get around this by wrapping your navigation element in a new `div` - let's call it nav-wrapper - and set its height to the same as your navigation element. These are known as placeholder elements. This new wrapper and your original navigation bar must always be the same height for the 'jump' to disappear.

```
<div class="nav-wrapper" style="height:80px;"> <-- add this

    <div class="your-original-nav" style="height:80px"></div>

</div> <!-- add this
```

Now, when you set the navigation bar to `fixed` and it disappears to the top, the new wrapper we created with the same height keeps the page's content the same. When the fixed class has been removed, it sits back in the wrapper again, without pushing the content down.

**A Suggestion**

From what I can see on your site, there will be a big gap where the navigation bar was until the new fixed navigation reaches that point and covers it. What you want, is a little jQuery to figure out where to make the navigation fixed and where to hide it. I'll explain:

```
// cache the element
var $navBar = $('.your-original-nav');

// find original navigation bar position
var navPos = $navBar.offset().top;

// on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {

    // get scroll position from top of the page
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // check if scroll position is >= the nav position
    if (scrollPos >= navPos) {
        $navBar.addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $navBar.removeClass('fixed');
    }

});
```

You may want to add further functionality to this example, as it is very, very basic. You would probably want to recalculate the offsets on window resize as one addition.

**A Demo**

[This is a little demo which might help you](http://jsfiddle.net/1e1cg6t5/) - I was bored and feeling helpful :)

Comment: This is such a sick answer. Makes so much sense when you see it explained. Thanks as well for the fiddle.

Comment: It's 2020 and this reply is still helping people. It makes so much sense.. Stick it in a div of the same height then pluck the inner div out without affecting the flow of the page. So simple, yet i spent half hour trying to figure it out. Thanks for explaining it so eloquently.

Comment: This is helpful, but it would be nicer if the demo were SFW.

Answer (score 4):

Made it this way now: Added an element before the nav:

```
<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>
```

And the jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("scroll",function(){
        if($(document).scrollTop()>150){
            $(".nav-placeholder").height($(".nav").outerHeight());
        } else {
            $(".nav-placeholder").height(0);
        }
    });
</script>
```

When I scroll down to 150 the placeholder gets the height of the nav, when i scroll up again I set it's height to 0.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/herrfischerhamburg/562wu62y/

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a placeholder when your nav goes from relative to fixed.
Therefore you need to make a new div.

```
jQuery(".nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery(".nav").outerHeight());


    jQuery(".nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
```

Remember to change ".nav", "nav-inner" and "nav-placeholder" to your desire.

For a fully functional sticky nav, check my website: http://www.swegre.se/

Comment: Thanks! Would you be willing to provide maybe a more detailed step set so I can do this? Would I put the placeholder div above/below the curent div and just target it with the code? Is that all I'd have to do? What does the inner do? Thanks! Forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem differently so on firefox as you can see in logs it scroll up itself so to stop this scrolling I made simple statement

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var header = $('#left-menu');
        var offset = header.offset().top;
        var up = true;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
            console.log(scroll + ' ' + offset )
            if (scroll >= offset) {
                header.addClass('sidebar-sticky');
                if (up){
                    $(window).scrollTop(offset);
                    up=false;

                }


            } else {
                up=true;
                header.removeClass('sidebar-sticky');
            }
        });


    });
```

that solution work for me when I can't specify height of div's I use.