# Weird scroll behaviour with JQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with smooth scrolling on my page with JQuery's animate function. It jumps, toggles between 2 divs when clicked twice on menu button and  offert anchor doesn't work at all.

Is it connected to scroll even listener?

HTML Code:

```
<menu id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul id="menu-ul">
       <li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="#about">O nas<div id="menu-decoration-1" class="menu-a-decoration"></div></a></li>
       <li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="#portfolio">Portfolio<div id="menu-decoration-2" class="menu-a-decoration"></div></a></li>
       <li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="#offert">Oferta<div id="menu-decoration-3" class="menu-a-decoration"></div></a></li>
       <li class="menu-li"><a class="menu-a" href="#contact">Kontakt<div id="menu-decoration-4" class="menu-a-decoration"></div></a></li>
    </ul>
</menu>
```

JQuery function:

```
 var aArray=["#about", "#portfolio", "#offert", "#contact"];    

  $(".menu-a").click(function(event){
    var index=$(".menu-a").index(this);
    console.log(index);
    $("#body-wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$(aArray[index]).offset().top}, 
   500);
  });
```

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Dassin/yae0kk7j/3/)**

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: It is caused because of the position fixed that you add on your javascript once you click the anchor... have a look at this it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864210/sticky-navigation-element-jumps-during-scroll

Comment: I dont think it is it... In place of menu there's a margin from header. The menu is in range of header's margin.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click on one of the buttons, the `offset().top` changes for each index. This is a bit of a dirty workaround but try this:

```
$(".menu-a").click(function(event){
    var index=$(".menu-a").index(this);
    console.log(index);
    $("#body-wrapper").animate({scrollTop:$(aArray[index]).offset().top - 
    $(aArray[0]).offset().top}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great, but it created another problem. The menu seems to jump now when clicked on a button. May i know what caused this mess?

Comment: Umm, i refreshed the page, and your comments disappeared. What was i supposed to change?

Comment: Lol sorry the change I suggested didn't work and I deleted the comment, still looking into it.