# Vertical scroll jumps when menubar fixes to top of screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a web page with a menu header that, when the page is scrolled down, fixes to the top when the menu header reaches the top of the page. But the code I found (absolute javascript beginner) and implemented creates a jump in the scrolling. From what I understand, this has to do with the css div height "vanishing" once I fix it to the top of the page.
HTML:

```
  <div class="home-header">
    <div class="caption">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="header" id="header">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="">PAGE 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PAGE 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PAGE 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PAGE 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.home-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495443396064-16fd983acb6a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 35vw;
}
.caption {
  color: #f2f2ee;
}
/* NAVIGATION */
.header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #888;
}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #18361f;
  width: 100%;
  background: #888;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    var sticky = header.offsetTop;

    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
        header.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o08c4j7d/1/) of the code with the problem. I currently run the javascript code directly in my html file with `<script> </script>` commands. I've tried the stackexchange answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864210/sticky-navigation-element-jumps-during-scroll), but it doesn't work, and another solution I found (I can't find the stackexchange page anymore), causes the menubar to jump to the top of the browser screen before it should actually arrive there. Is there another solution I can use to fix this scroll jumping issue? (I did add the jquery api into the header of my html when I ran the above solution code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just CSS no JavaScript required. I've modified your fiddle to do just that.

I added these to your header CSS class.

```
position: sticky;
top: 0;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jd3etnyc/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.home-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495443396064-16fd983acb6a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 35vw;
}

.caption {
  color: #f2f2ee;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #888;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #18361f;
  width: 100%;
  background: #888;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header">
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header" id="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
blabla1<br>blabla2<br>blabla3<br>blabla4<br>blabla5<br>blabla6<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla
<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla<br>blabla
```

Comment: That's beautiful, thanks! Is there a reason some people prefer using javascript to achieve this? It's hard to beat two lines of code. . . .

Comment: I'm unsure. likely they just aren't aware of the css properties

Comment: @sebastianross This may not be true for the OP, but it's likely due to browser support requirements. There's plenty of us that would like to use certain solutions, but because we have to support certain, older browser (*cough* <IE11) you don't have a choice. So some posters post solutions that have broader browser support by default. Many posters, if using fairly new features will say so and ask that you check something like caniuse.com before implementing.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `position: sticky;`...

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

... it's rather new so watch your browser version requirements.

Edit: a pen for this... https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/yLyMZYE

Answer (score 0):

Sticky headers overlay other elements on the page. Prior to scrolling, you will need to add a "buffer" to the content so it is not initially overlay-ed. This buffer is achieved with margin/padding and usually starts with an amount that matches the height of the sticky header.

Below I've updated your code to add this "buffer" via a class.

Note: This is for sticky headers using fixed positioning.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("header");
var main   = document.querySelector( 'main' );
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
    main.classList.add( 'sticky-buffer' );
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
    main.classList.remove( 'sticky-buffer' );
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.home-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495443396064-16fd983acb6a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80') center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 35vw;
}

.caption {
  color: #f2f2ee;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.header {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: proxima-nova, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  background: #888;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #18361f;
  width: 100%;
  background: #888;
}

.sticky-buffer {
  padding-top: 60px; /* <-- .header height */
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-header">
  <div class="caption">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header" id="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="">PAGE 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">PAGE 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<main>
  blabla1
  <br> blabla2
  <br> blabla3
  <br> blabla4
  <br> blabla5
  <br> blabla6
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
  <br> blabla
</main>
```

Comment: ```position: fixed;``` is not ```position: sticky;```; Sticky acts like static until the element hits the point you define in any of "top", "right", "bottom" or "left". Check this pen: https://codepen.io/bstees/pen/yLyMZYE

Comment: Never said it was. Any header that sticks to the top of the page, regardless of the position value, is colloquially referred to as a _"sticky"_ header. I also noted in my post that this solution is for sticky headers using `position: fixed`.