# Navbar is bouncing on scroll when getting "stickied" to the top

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

For some reason, whenever I scroll my navbar and it "sticks" as a fixed element on the screen, it creates a bouncing/jumping effect. Naturally, I do not want this!

This is the website: https://julia.higson.ca/

I've tried methods of changing the height of the `nav` and `nav-wrap` elements, but to no effect. Any help would be much appreciated.

Bits of code below:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // Check your elements
  $.fn.checkNavPositioning = function($el, $nav, scrollClass) {
    var navHeight = $nav.outerHeight();

    if(((this.outerHeight() - $(window).scrollTop()) < $nav.outerHeight()) && !$el.hasClass(scrollClass)) {
      $el.addClass(scrollClass);
      $el.css('padding-top', navHeight);
    } else if((this.outerHeight() >= $(window).scrollTop()) && $el.hasClass(scrollClass)) {
      $el.removeClass(scrollClass);
      $el.css('padding-top', 0);
    }
  }

  // Mobile sidebars
  $.fn.expandableSidebar = function(expandedClass) {
    var $me = this;

    $me.on('click', function() {
      if(!$me.hasClass(expandedClass)) {
        $me.addClass(expandedClass);
        $me.hide();
        $me.removeClass("active");
      } else {
        $me.removeClass(expandedClass);
        $me.hide();
        $me.removeClass("active");
      }
    });
  }

  // Interval loop
  $.fn.intervalLoop = function(condition, action, duration, limit) {
    var counter = 0;
    var looper = setInterval(function(){
      if (counter >= limit || $.fn.checkIfElementExists(condition)) {
        clearInterval(looper);
      } else {
        action();
        counter++;
      }
    }, duration);
  }

  // Check if element exists
  $.fn.checkIfElementExists = function(selector) {
    return $(selector).length;
  }


  var centoController = {
    init: function(opts) {
      var base = this;

      // Check content positioning
      if($(window).width() > 767) {
        $('.cento-header').checkNavPositioning($('body:not(.wsite-checkout-page)'), $('.nav-wrap'), 'affix');
      }

      // Add classes to elements
      base._addClasses();
        base._attachEvents();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $.fn.intervalLoop('', base._checkCartItems, 800, 3);
        }, 500);
    },

    _addClasses: function() {
      var base = this;

      // Add class to nav items with subnav
      $('.wsite-menu-default').find('li.wsite-menu-item-wrap').each(function(){
        var $me = $(this);

        if($me.children('.wsite-menu-wrap').length > 0) {

          $me.addClass('has-submenu');
          $('<span class="icon-caret"></span>').insertAfter($me.children('a.wsite-menu-item'));
        }
      });

      // Add class to subnav items with subnav
      $('.wsite-menu').find('li.wsite-menu-subitem-wrap').each(function(){
        var $me = $(this);

        if($me.children('.wsite-menu-wrap').length > 0) {

          $me.addClass('has-submenu');
          $('<span class="icon-caret"></span>').insertAfter($me.children('a.wsite-menu-subitem'));
        }
      });

      // Keep subnav open if submenu item is active
    $('li.wsite-menu-subitem-wrap.wsite-nav-current').parents('.wsite-menu-wrap').addClass('open');

      // Add placeholder text to inputs
      $('.wsite-form-sublabel').each(function(){
        var sublabel = $(this).text();
        $(this).prev('.wsite-form-input').attr('placeholder', sublabel);
      });

      // Add fullwidth class to gallery thumbs if less than 6
      $('.imageGallery').each(function(){
        if ($(this).children('div').length <= 6) {
          $(this).children('div').addClass('fullwidth-mobile');
        }
      });
    },

    _checkCartItems: function() {
      var base = this;

      if($('#wsite-mini-cart').find('li.wsite-product-item').length > 0) {
        $('body').addClass('cart-full');
      } else {
        $('body').removeClass('cart-full');
      }
    },

    _moveLogin: function() {
      var loginDetach = $('#member-login').detach();
      $('.mobile-nav .wsite-menu-default > li:last-child').after(loginDetach);
    },

    _attachEvents: function() {
      var base = this;

        // Nav toggle
        $('.hamburger').on('click', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
            if(!$('body').hasClass('nav-open')) {
                $('body').addClass('nav-open');
            } else {
                $('body').toggleClass('nav-open');
                $('body').removeClass('nav-open');
            }
        });
        
        // Nav toggle AFTER CLICKING ON ANCHOR LINK 
        $('.nav li a').on('click', function(e){
            $('body').removeClass('nav-open');
        });

      // Move cart + login
      if ($(window).width() <= 992) {
        $.fn.intervalLoop('.mobile-nav #member-login', base._moveLogin, 800, 5);
      }

      // Window scroll
      $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        // Affix nav
        if($(window).width() > 767) {
          $('.cento-header').checkNavPositioning($('body:not(.wsite-checkout-page)'), $('.nav-wrap'), 'affix');
        }
      });

        // Subnav toggle
        $('li.has-submenu span.icon-caret').on('click', function() {
            var $me = $(this);

            if($me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').hasClass('open')) {
                $me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').removeClass('open');
            } else {
                $me.siblings('.wsite-menu-wrap').addClass('open');
            }
        });


      // Store category dropdown
      $('.wsite-com-sidebar').expandableSidebar('sidebar-expanded');

      // Search filters dropdown
      $('#wsite-search-sidebar').expandableSidebar('sidebar-expanded');

      // Init fancybox swipe on mobile
      if ('ontouchstart' in window) {
        $('body').on('click', 'a.w-fancybox', function() {
          base._initSwipeGallery();
        });
      }

      $('.wsite-product-button, #wsite-com-product-add-to-cart, .wsite-product-item .wsite-remove-button').on('click', function(){
          setTimeout(function() { base._checkCartItems(); }, 800);
        });
    },

    _initSwipeGallery: function() {
      var base = this;

      setTimeout(function(){
        var touchGallery = document.getElementsByClassName('fancybox-wrap')[0];
        var mc = new Hammer(touchGallery);
        mc.on("panleft panright", function(ev) {
          if (ev.type == "panleft") {
            $("a.fancybox-next").trigger("click");
          } else if (ev.type == "panright") {
            $("a.fancybox-prev").trigger("click");
          }
          base._initSwipeGallery();
        });
      }, 500);
    }
  }
  
    //**** ScrollSpy ****//
    // Cache selectors
    var lastId,
        topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
          var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
          if (item.length) { return item; }
        });

    // Bind click handler to menu items
    // so we can get a fancy scroll animation
    menuItems.click(function(e){
      var href = $(this).attr("href"),
          offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
          scrollTop: offsetTop
      }, 300);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       // Get container scroll position
       var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;
   
       // Get id of current scroll item
       var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
         if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
           return this;
       });
       // Get the id of the current element
       cur = cur[cur.length-1];
       var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
   
       if (lastId !== id) {
           lastId = id;
           // Set/remove active class
           menuItems
             .parent().removeClass("active")
             .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
       }                   
    });
    

  $(document).ready(function(){
    centoController.init();
  });

});
```

```css
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento:400,700);
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic);
/* Resets */
ul,
ol,
li,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
pre,
form,
body,
html,
p,
blockquote,
fieldset,
input {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Global Styles */
html {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #3e3e3e;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 25px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
a {
  color: #b9b9b9;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #fa8a86;
}
a img,
a:hover img {
  border: none;
}
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
p,
div.paragraph {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
blockquote {
  font-style: italic;
  border-left: 4px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #888;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder,
:-moz-placeholder,
::-moz-placeholder,
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #777777;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
textarea:focus {
  border: 1px solid #777777;
}
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
.wsite-form-field,
.wsite-com-product-option-groups {
  input[type="radio"],
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #444444 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  input[type="radio"] {
    border-radius: 8px;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  input[type="radio"]:after {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    content: "";
  }
  input[type="radio"]:checked:after {
    background: #444444;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 6px;
    border: solid #444444;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
  }
}
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Fixed nav */
body.affix .cento-header .nav-wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 15;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
  overflow-anchor: none;
  
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("Cover.jpg");
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
/* Editor Overrides :: DO NOT REMOVE */
#icontent .container {
  overflow: visible;
}
/* Header */
.cento-header {
  /*height: 100%;*/
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 100%;
  /*background: #ffffff;*/
  background: transparent;
  padding: 150px 0 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("Cover.jpg");
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.cento-header .logo {
  margin-bottom: 320px;
}
.cento-header .logo img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.cento-header .logo #wsite-title {
  display: block;
  max-width: 500px;
}
.cento-header .logo,
.cento-header .logo a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: .04em;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: normal;
}
.cento-header .nav-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  /*background: #ffffff;*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.cento-header .hamburger {
  display: none;
}
/* Nav */
.nav {
  text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
.nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 100px;
  /*color: #b9b9b9;*/
  color: #000000;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .07em;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*font-weight: 400;*/
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 19px;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-out;
}
#top-menu a:hover {
  /*text-decoration: underline;*/ 
  border-bottom-color: #fa8a86;
}
#top-menu li.active a {
  border-bottom-color: black;
}
.nav ul li#active > a.wsite-menu-item,
.nav ul li > a.wsite-menu-item:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
.mobile-nav {
  display: none;
}
/* Submenu */
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu {
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .07em;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover {
  color: #333333;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu li a:hover .wsite-menu-arrow:before {
  color: #333333;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;
}
#wsite-menus .wsite-menu-arrow:before {
  display: block;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  content: '\203A';
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 11px;
}
/* Banner */

.wsite-background,
.wsite-header-section {
  position: relative;
  background: url(images/default-bg.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.banner-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1115px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}
.wsite-header-section:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  content: ' ';
}
.wsite-section-bg-color:before {
  display: none;
}
.banner-wrap .container {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.banner-wrap .banner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.banner-wrap .banner h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 50px;
}
.banner-wrap .banner p {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .button-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button,
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-large {
  text-align: center !important;
  background: transparent;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button .wsite-button-inner,
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-large .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #333333;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button:hover .wsite-button-inner,
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-large:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid #333333;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-highlight .wsite-button-inner,
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-large.wsite-button-highlight .wsite-button-inner {
  background: transparent;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-highlight:hover .wsite-button-inner,
.banner-wrap .banner .wsite-button-large.wsite-button-highlight:hover .wsite-button-inner {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #333333 !important;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
/* Content */
.content-wrap {
  background: #ffffff;
}
.content-wrap .container {
  padding: 40px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh; /*Set to full viewport high*/
}
/* Header page */
.header-page .wsite-header-section {
  height: 65vh;
}
/* No header page */
.no-header-page .content-wrap .container {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body class='no-header-page  wsite-theme-light'>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cento-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">WEB TITLE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-wrap">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="nav desktop-nav">
            <ul class="wsite-menu-default" id="top-menu">  
              <li><a class="active" href="#about"> ABOUT </a></li>
              <li><a href="#work"> WORK </a></li>
              <li><a href="#experience"> EXPERIENCE </a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div><!-- end .container -->
      </div><!-- end .nav-wrap -->
    </div><!-- end .header -->

    <div class="content-wrap">
      <p>Hello world</p>
    </div><!-- end content-wrap -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/files/theme/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat I can tell you it's because you navbar is removed from the layout when it sticks... Which changes the value of the scroll offset which in turn 'bounces' the rest of the elements.

What you can do is wrap it in a container with a fixed height and leave the wrapper during the stick event.

Comment: So I tried wrapping `.nav` with a wrapper and setting their `height` to be the same, as per this example [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864210/sticky-navigation-element-jumps-during-scroll), but still getting the flickering ... Any other tips perchance?

Comment: I see you're also adding an inline style of `padding-top: 84px` to the body when the header sticks. When I added the property `padding-top: 0px !important;` in the `body` ruleset the content jumping was gone. And only the header flicker remains. Which is caused by the sticky trigger overlapping between two scroll offsets, when it should be more like a switch. i.e `sticky = window.scrollTop < 400 ? true : false`

Comment: It's bad practise to use `!important` in your css. I use it mostly for testing. And sorry I'm not giving you the exact code you need to edit as there's a lot of it. But I'm closely familiar with these kind of problems and hope I can guide you towards a solution of your own.

Comment: Ok found the line. Remove `$el.css('padding-top', navHeight);` instead of adding `padding-top: 0px !important;` for the jumping to seize.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I tried all your tips, but the thing that eventually worked for me was changing in `header`: `height: 100vh` to `height: 100%`. Not sure why, but turning off `vh` stops the flickering of the navbar when scrolling ...